# pyodbc update record with binary data in MS SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to update an existing record with binary data.

The sql server datatype for the column is a varbinary(MAX)

The python code I use:

```
result = bytes(result_string, 'utf-8')
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
date_updated = self.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE _nsInvoiceReconitionJob SET JobStatus = 2, DateUpdated = '{date_updated}', Result = '{result}' WHERE ID = '{job_id}'")
connection.commit()
```

The result is the following:

```
File "/home/wessel/Work/crontest/Elvpy/JobProcessing.py", line 37, in save_result
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE _nsInvoiceReconitionJob SET JobStatus = 2, DateUpdated = '{date_updated}', Result = '{result}' WHERE ID = '{job_id}'")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

The error mentions that this could be a syntax error, and the query works without updating the "Result" column, which is the binary data column. This means the error has to be the binary data, so I tried it without '', but that doesn't work either.
It could also not be a syntax error, and mean that I'm just doing this wrong. If anyone could set me on the right path I would be most grateful!

I am using pyodbc version 4.0.30,
I use the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Comment: SQL injection! Use parameters. See [cursor.execute docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id16).

Comment: In this case there is no risk for SQL injection because there is 0 user input, but I will look into it :)

Comment: Yes, but as you've noticed, using f-strings requires that you quote the values correctly, which you evidently are unable to do given the varbinary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id16)!

```py
result = bytes(result_string, 'utf-8')
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
date_updated = self.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
cursor.execute(
    "UPDATE _nsInvoiceReconitionJob SET JobStatus = ?, DateUpdated = ?, Result = ? WHERE ID = ?"
    , (2, date_updated, result, job_id)
    )
connection.commit()
```